# Join between Tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have 5 tables

```
1. SCHOOL[id(bigInt, primary), name(varchar)]
2. SELECTED_INDICATOR[id(bigInt, primary), school_id(bigint)]
3. TEACHER[id(bigint, primary), indicator_id(bigInt), attendance_id(int)]
4. STUDENT[id(bigint, primary), indicator_id(bigInt), attendance_id(int)]
5. MIDDAY_MEAL[id(bigint,primary), indicator_id(bigint), served(boolean), consumed_number(int)]
```

in TEACHER table, attendance_id can have value: 1 or 2 or 3. 
Similarly, in STUDENT table, attendance_id can have value: 1 or 2.

I have to generate a report based on the SELECTED_INDICATOR id, in a format as:

School_id | School_Name | Total_Teacher | Teacher_1 | Teacher_2 | Teacher_3 | Total_Student | Student_1 | Student_2 | served | consumed_number

for this I have tried as:

```
select A.id, A.school_id, SC.name, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN T.attendance_id IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL_TEACHER,
 SUM(CASE WHEN T.attendance_id IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TEACHERS_1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN T.attendance_id IN (2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TEACHERS_2,
 SUM(CASE WHEN T.attendance_id IN (3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TEACHERS_3,
 SUM(CASE WHEN S.attendance_id IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL_STUDENT,
 SUM(CASE WHEN S.attendance_id IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as STUDENTS_1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN S.attendance_id IN (2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as STUDENTS_2,
 M.served, M.consumed_number
from SELECTED_INDICATOR A
join SCHOOL SC on A.school_id = SC.id
join TEACHER T on A.id = T.indicator_id
join STUDENT S on A.id = S.indicator_id
join MIDDAY_MEAL M on A.id = M.indicator_id
WHERE A.STATUS = 'COMPLETED' group by A.id;
```

When I join TEACHER or STUDENT with SELECTED_INDICATOR one at a time, it gives me the correct data. But when I join both the TEACHER and STUDENT with SELECTED_INDICATOR as in the above query, I get huge numbers for teacher and student related fields.

what is wrong with my query? Please help to correct it, or give any alternative query.

Comment: What is the relevance of midday_meal? why include it at all? Frankly the data model looks quite strange and I would like to see a few rows of data from each table.

Comment: Also, don't rely on MySQL's non-standard approach to GROUP BY you should specify every non-aggregating column in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: change your group by to this; GROUP BY A.id, A.school_id, SC.Name, M.served, M.consumed_number

Comment: Thanks for your support,  I got the solution in #sagi answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `COUNT()` that have the options to use distincted values. The problem is that the tables are multiplying the results.

```
    select A.id, A.school_id, SC.name, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN T.attendance_id IN (1,2,3) THEN t.TeacherID  END) as TOTAL_TEACHER,
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN T.attendance_id IN (1) THEN t.TeacherID END) as TEACHERS_1,
    ....
    FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT A.id, A.school_id, SC.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(T.attendance_id) FROM TEACHER T GROUP BY T.indicator_id HAVING A.id = T.indicator_id) AS TOTAL_TEACHER,
    (SELECT COUNT(T.attendance_id) FROM TEACHER T WHERE T.attendance_id = 1 GROUP BY T.indicator_id HAVING A.id = T.indicator_id) AS TEACHERS_1,
    (SELECT COUNT(T.attendance_id) FROM TEACHER T WHERE T.attendance_id = 2 GROUP BY T.indicator_id HAVING A.id = T.indicator_id) AS TEACHERS_2,
    (SELECT COUNT(T.attendance_id) FROM TEACHER T WHERE T.attendance_id = 3 GROUP BY T.indicator_id HAVING A.id = T.indicator_id) AS TEACHERS_3,
    (SELECT COUNT(S.attendance_id) FROM STUDENT S GROUP BY S.indicator_id HAVING A.id = S.indicator_id) AS TOTAL_STUDENT,
    (SELECT COUNT(S.attendance_id) FROM STUDENT S WHERE S.attendance_id = 1 GROUP BY S.indicator_id HAVING A.id = S.indicator_id) AS STUDENTS_1,
    (SELECT COUNT(S.attendance_id) FROM STUDENT S WHERE S.attendance_id = 2 GROUP BY S.indicator_id HAVING A.id = S.indicator_id) AS STUDENTS_2,
    M.served, M.consumed_number
    FROM SELECTED_INDICATOR A
    JOIN SCHOOL SC on A.school_id = SC.id
    JOIN MIDDAY_MEAL M on A.id = M.indicator_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But it gives multiple rows for the sub queries.

Comment: Now You can check.